# Emails can not be sent

Tags: macbook-pro

I can't send emails from my Macbook Pro. Whenever I try to do so, a message comes up showing the message'Connections to host IMAP on the default ports failed' Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide additional details?  For instance, are you using the Mail app?  Have you been able to connect before or is this your first time trying to connect?  What version of OS X are you using?  The more details about what you are doing and trying to do goes a long way in rendering assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to make sure is that Mail's 'smart' settings haven't changed your port & settings...

In Mail prefs > Accounts > Outgoing Mail Server SMTP: Edit SMTP Server List...

[image]

Check that the port & SSL details are correct, & disable 'Automatically detect & maintain account settings'

[image]